# mongo update pipeline update nested array

Tags: mongodb-query

I am trying to update the nested array based on filter condition, and i am struggling to update nested array. please suggest how it can be written.

Example document:

```
    {
      "_id": "67448af8-a68b-4d08-8948-2cddca57d708",
      "identity": {
        "_id": "7.26Demo@test.com",
        "type": "Email"
      },
      "type": "User",
      "links": [
        {
          "linkType": "Org",
          "linkPath": "0923689a-e009-4d67-8db5-5ba40f840bf3/facd3c31-dbfd-4097-9a27-0d862bb0c8e9",
          "status": "Activated",
          "createdOn": {
            "$date": "2022-07-26T14:49:38.780Z"
          },
          "createdBy": ""
        }
      ],
      "memberOfGroups": [
        {
          "_id": "ba93384d-d18a-4b36-9a24-7d3ebb1619d7",
          "name": "test group"
        }
      ],
      "roles": [
        {
          "_id": "ba93384d-d18a-4b36-9a24-7d3ebb1619d7",
          "name": "test group",
          "sources": [
            {
              "type": "group",
              "linkType": "app",
              "groupId": "ba93384d-d18a-4b36-9a24-7d3ebb1619d7"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

i am using below pipeline but not able to update the role sources array.

```
db.principals.update({
  _id: "67448af8-a68b-4d08-8948-2cddca57d708"
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      "memberOfGroups": {$ifNull: ["$memberOfGroups", []]}
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "roles": {$ifNull: ["$roles", []]}
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "memberOfGroups": {
        $cond: [
          {
            $ne: [
              "$memberOfGroups._id",
              "ba93384d-d18a-4b36-9a24-7d3ebb1619d7"
            ]
          },
          {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$memberOfGroups.items",
              [
                {
                  _id: "ba93384d-d18a-4b36-9a24-7d3ebb1619d7",
                  name: "test group"
                }
              ]
            ]
          },
          {$concatArrays: ["$memberOfGroups.items", []]}
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      "roles": {
        $cond: [
          {
            $ne: [
              "$roles._id",
              "ba93384d-d18a-4b36-9a24-7d3ebb1619d7"
            ]
          },
          {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$roles.items",
              [
                {
                  _id: "ba93384d-d18a-4b36-9a24-7d3ebb1619d7",
                  name: "test group",
                  sources: [
                    {
                      type: "group",
                      linkType: "app",
                      groupId: "ba93384d-d18a-4b36-9a24-7d3ebb1619d7"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            ]
          },
          {}
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      roles: {
        $reduce: {
          input: {$ifNull: ["$roles", []]},
          initialValue: {
            role: {
              _id: "0923689a-e009-4d67-8db5-5ba40f840bf3",
              name: "testRole",
              sources: [
                {
                  type: "group",
                  linkType: "org"
                }
              ]
            },
            sources: [
              {
                type: "group",
                linkType: "org",
                groupid: "0923689a-e009-4d67-8db5-5ba40f840bf3"
              }
            ]
          },
          in: {
            $cond: [
              {$eq: [
                  "$$this.roleid",
                  "0923689a-e009-4d67-8db5-5ba40f840bf3"
                ]
              },
              {$cond: [
                  {$ne: [
                      "$$this.sources.groupId",
                      "0923689a-e009-4d67-8db5-5ba40f840bf3"
                    ]
                  },
                  {$concatArrays: ["$$this.sources", "$$value.sources"]},
                  {$concatArrays: ["$$this.sources", []]}
                ]
              },
              {}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

In the above third stage is not working properly where i am trying to insert in role array item source array.

I want to accomplish three things.

1. If memberOfGroups array doesn't have groupId
   Add a memberOfGroup Object in the array.
2. Roles array is not having element with matching roleId
   Add one Role object in array containing
3. Role array has matching row with roleid but source is not there with matching groupid
   Add the source object in the matching role element.

[mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/I4SMX0z-LIi) with above example document and aggregation pipeline.

Comment: Your example document doesn't look quite right.  Did you mean, `"roles": [{"_id": "123"}, {"sources": []}]}]`?

Comment: It’s correct sources array can be in each roles array element.

Comment: And `"roles"` should be an array of objects, yes?

Comment: yes rick its correct.

Comment: I don't think `"roles": ["_id": "123", "sources": []]` is a valid JSON nor BSON array.

Comment: {"_id":"67448af8-a68b-4d08-8948-2cddca57d708","identity":{"_id":"7.26Demo@test.com","type":"Email"},"type":"User","links":[{"linkType":"Org","linkPath":"0923689a-e009-4d67-8db5-5ba40f840bf3/facd3c31-dbfd-4097-9a27-0d862bb0c8e9","status":"Activated","createdOn":{"$date":"2022-07-26T14:49:38.780Z"},"createdBy":""}],"memberOfGroups":[{"_id":"ba93384d-d18a-4b36-9a24-7d3ebb1619d7","name":"test group"}],"roles":[{"_id":"ba93384d-d18a-4b36-9a24-7d3ebb1619d7","name":"test group","sources":[{"type":"group","linkType":"app","groupId":"ba93384d-d18a-4b36-9a24-7d3ebb1619d7"}]}]}

Comment: here is a valid sample doc in mongo

Comment: The update pipeline looks to be overly complicated and the logic is difficult to follow,  Perhaps if you explain your logic and show the desired updated document (given the example document), it might be easier to suggested an improved pipeline.

Comment: updated details in question.